# enabling options from shopt terminal output in ubuntu server 12.4 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, runlevel

I just installed Ubuntu Server and is typical of Ubuntu Installs (for me anyway) I'm lost. With the Desktop version I can never figure out the sudoers file and wheel group through SELinux, but this time I installed the Server edition 12.4 LTS. I have no GUI and have decided I'm gonna have to work at the command line to learn how to use this because startx (usually used for a GUI in Linux distributions) is just starting the X Org Server. My problem could like in the default runlevel, but I've skipped checking that for now because I'm more curious about the shopt command. I get a list of settings that are turned off and while I'm a minimalist, I'm a maximizing minimalist and I want these options on. Can anyone tell me how I can turn on the settings in this list that I get from the shopt command?

[image]

Comment: It... doesn't sound like you should really be using the server edition...

Answer (score 2):

The last line is the only part of your "question" that looks like a question, so I will answer that.

You can enable a shopt option for bash with the following command `shop -s OPTION` where 'OPTION' is the option you wish to enable.

Please read the [man](http://ss64.com/bash/shopt.html) page for  `shopt`...

Comment: thankyou so much, I do ramble. English isn't my stronger trait. that's obnoxiousness!